# How to exclude from multidimentional array values on condition given in another array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays where Array1 keys are [teacher_id] in Array2:

```
Array1 ( [20] => 37 [44] => 40 )

Array2
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [teacher_id] => 44
            [course_id] => 1180
            [student_id] => 1662
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [teacher_id] => 20
            [course_id] => 1180
            [student_id] => 1662
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [teacher_id] => 44
            [course_id] => 1180
            [student_id] => 1705
        )
)
```

I need to exclude this part from Array2:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [teacher_id] => 44
        [course_id] => 1180
        [student_id] => 1662
    )
```

on condition that in array1 value 37 <  value 40.

I tried array_filter but I can't figure out how to write proper function for that.
Thank you.

Comment: What are the values for the first array?

Comment: `on condition that in array1 value 37 < value 40.` what does this mean, Exactly?

Comment: You should do this in an Sql query while fetching the data.

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```
$array1 = array ( '20' => 37, '44' => 40 );       


$array2 = array (
    0 => 
    array (
        'teacher_id' => 44,
        'course_id' => 1180,
        'student_id' => 1662
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
        'teacher_id' => 20,
        'course_id' => 1180,
        'student_id' => 1662
    ),
    2 => 
    array (
        'teacher_id' => 44,
        'course_id' => 1180,
        'student_id' => 1705
    )
);



$array = array_filter($array2, function($item) use ($array1){
    $key = $item['teacher_id'];

    if(!isset($array1[$key])) return true; //always keep these
    return $item['teacher_id'] > $array1[$key];
});

print_r($array);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [teacher_id] => 44
            [course_id] => 1180
            [student_id] => 1662
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [teacher_id] => 44
            [course_id] => 1180
            [student_id] => 1705
        )

)
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/000137cb611ea91e967035703bdadf86ec05cba4)

Notice the `use ($array1)` but what you intend to do with it after that is a mystery.

I am not sure if this

> I need to exclude this part from Array2:

Means to keep only that or remove only that.  Your question is very ambiguous I don't know what this `I need to exclude this part from Array2 .. on condition that in array1 value 37 < value 40.` means

Let me re-word that.

You need to exclude some bit, from `$array2` on the condition of `$array1` [something] value `37` is less then [something] value `40`.

And I guess this means

```
 I have two arrays where Array1 keys are [teacher_id] in Array2:
```

That `20 => 37` (from `$array1`) goes with `'teacher_id' => 20` (from `$array2`)

But how do I do `on condition that in array1 value 37 < value 40` on that?  Neither of those values come from `$array2`.

Comment: My goal is to remove the subarray0 from array2. Based on:  'course_id' AND 'student_id' are equal to subarray1, but 'teacher_id' lead to array1 and array1 shows that teacher with id=44 (and the whole subarray0) must be removed as 37<40. I hope I could explain it right.

Comment: Sorry it still doesn't make sense.  Not in a way I can convert that to instructions in my head that need to be executed in code. How is `'course_id' AND 'student_id' are equal to subarray1`  What if you need to remove the 5th item etc.  How do you know what to compare.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$array1 = array('20' => 37, '44' => 40);
$array2 = array(array
        (
        'teacher_id' => 44,
        'course_id' => 1180,
        'student_id' => 1662
    ),
    array
        (
        'teacher_id' => 20,
        'course_id' => 1180,
        'student_id' => 1662
    ),
    array
        (
        'teacher_id' => 44,
        'course_id' => 1180,
        'student_id' => 1705
        ));
$final_array = array_filter($array2, function($item) use ($array1) {
    return $array1[$item['teacher_id']] != max($array1);
});
```

Comment: What's this ugly stuff `$GLOBALS['array1']` why not pass it using `use` which is the correct best practice way.  Not to mention you never set it to begin with, so it's undefined index.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to remove the first element which is an array of the second array, based on a condition concerning the first array, you may [array_shift()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) it off as follows:

```
<?php
$arr1 = [20 => 37, 44 => 40];
$arr2 = [0 => [
            "teacher_id" => 44,
            "course_id" => 1180,
            "student_id" => 1662],

         1 => [
            "teacher_id" => 20,
            "course_id" => 1180,
            "student_id" => 1662
         ],
         2 => [
            "teacher_id" => 44,
            "course_id" => 1180,
            "student_id" => 1705
         ]];

/* 
remove first element in $arr2 so that teacher_ids commence with first key in first array
provided its value is less than the next one in $arr1 
*/

$arrvalues = array_values( $arr1 );
$i=0;
if ( $arrvalues[$i] < $arrvalues[$i+1] ) {
      array_shift( $arr2 );
      var_dump($arr2);
}
```

See live code [here](https://3v4l.org/ThvmU#output)

The function [array_values()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) facilitates working with values in an associative array. Alternatively, you may [unset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) the first element in $arr2; see [this example](https://3v4l.org/ZNn8o#output). Also, you may effectively remove that first element when the condition is met by taking a [slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) of the array; see [here](https://3v4l.org/WKVIF#output). If you are still determined to use [array_filter()](http://php.net/array_filter), see this [example](https://3v4l.org/VRcqN).